# php-fpm opcache インストールでエラー

Tags: php, nginx

```
[zendopcache]
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.enable = On
```

OpCacheをインストールして、PHP5.5.iniに上記を記述しました。php-fpmをrestartするとエラーになります。

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
```

こちらをコメントアウトすると再起動はできますので、これに問題があるかもしれません。

また、php-fpmのリスタートだけでなく、php -vでも下記のようなエラーが表示されます。
バージョンは

- php5.5.20
- zend opcache 7.0.3
- Amazon AWS EC2 micro t2 linux
- nginx

です。

エラー文

```
[root@ip-********* ~]# /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
php-fpm-5.5 を停止中:                                      [  OK  ]
php-fpm-5.5 を起動中: [31-Jan-2015 12:33:32] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Module 'Zend OPcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[31-Jan-2015 12:33:32] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Zend OPcache: module registration failed! in Unknown on line 0
*** Error in `php-fpm-5.5': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffd35a4faf8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7638e)[0x7ffd526c838e]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x770f7)[0x7ffd526c90f7]
php-fpm-5.5(php_module_shutdown+0x2b)[0x53360b]
php-fpm-5.5[0x64cd19]
php-fpm-5.5[0x645f06]
php-fpm-5.5[0x652eb1]
php-fpm-5.5[0x6451d3]
php-fpm-5.5[0x421583]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7ffd526737d5]
php-fpm-5.5[0x42283d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-006fb000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396155                             /usr/sbin/php-fpm-5.5
008fb000-00984000 rw-p 002fb000 ca:01 396155                             /usr/sbin/php-fpm-5.5

====ここから似たような文字列がズラーっと====

7fffd0ec4000-7fffd0ee5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffd0f89000-7fffd0f8b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
中止
[root@ip-****** ~]# [31-Jan-2015 12:33:32] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Zend OPcache: module registration failed! in Unknown on line 0
-bash: [31-Jan-2015: コマンドが見つかりません
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
opcache.iniに
zend_extension=opcache.so
と有効になっていて重複していたのです。
;zend_extension=opcache.so
でphp-fpm restartでOKでした。

OCPでenableになり、メモリなど表記されました。